# preg_replace not doing what I expect

Tags: php

I have the following paterns in a paragraph of text and I need to replace it with nothing, so that it disappears from the paragraph.

The sendtence contains `CONSULTANTS [45416,2010-05-11]` I need to remove the [] and everything within these [] , not the characters within the [] could be anything

I tried the below but this only removes the []

```
$par = preg_replace('/[\[*\]]/','',$par);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
$par = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/s','',$par);
```

Explanation:

```
/    - Start delimiter
\[   - A literal [
.*?  - A non-greedy anything
\]   - A literal ]
/    - End delimiter
s    - Modifier to make . match even a newline
```

to make the replacement a bit faster you can do:

```
$par = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/s','',$par);
```

Explanation:

```
/    - Start delimiter
\[   - A literal [
 [   - Start of character class
 ^   - Char class negator
 ]   - End of character class
\]   - A literal ]
/    - End delimiter
```

Comment: Your explanation is so clear and thorough it almost made me cry.

Answer (score 2):

Roland,

What you are trying to match is:

```
[\[*\]]
```

Which is any of the '[', '*', ']' chars. What you really want is a pattern starting with '[' and ending with ']'. There can be any non-']' char in between. So the correct pattern would be:

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

So this:

```
$par = preg_replace("/\[[^\]]*\]/", "", $par);
```

should work.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to match [45416,2010-05-11]